# Apache Cordova Android 4.0.x branch - how to build?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I want to try out a new feature that is only in the 4.0.x branch of Apache Cordova.  reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3445 (If curious: there is new code to use Android Studio gradle build system instead of ANT)

How do I go about doing a source checkout and build of Cordova 4.0.x branch?  I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT:

Ok, so I have cordova-android - but how do I replace my existing Cordova 3.5.1 - I assume I need to download some other components.  I want to be able to do:

```
cordova create test1
cd test1
cordova platform add android
```

With this 4.0.x branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First clone as usual

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.git
$ cd cordova-android
```

Only `master` should be cloned. You can see the remote branches using

```
$ git branch -r
```

Then just fetch the one you want

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout 4.0.x
$ cat VERSION
4.0.0-dev
```

Comment: Thank you... But this gives me just the cordova-android, right? Aren't there more steps to update the non-android parts and to compile and/or install them?  I added an Edit to the question.

Comment: Ahh - I think I figured it out ;) run cordova-android/bin/create